# editing a file on external server with php

Tags: php

I am trying to edit an external file. I have changed file's chmods (666) and I can read the file using file_get_contents but i am unable to put content:

> [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections

how can I solve that problem?

is there any way to edit files on external servers? maybe you can suggest better method

Comment: what kind of file do you want to change?

Comment: php file and txt file - tried to change both and failed twice

Comment: you want to change the external file and then store it as well at that external server? Or do you want to change the file and store the changed version on your own server?

Comment: it is on my second server but it can looks like this - i want to change chmods of the file (local file with chmod()) and then edit and change chmods again to protect the file

Comment: i want to edit external file - read, change and save on external server but using script on a different one

Comment: It's best if the receiving end of this would have some sort of API to request and edition of the files. It's far safer and better than editing the file directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CHMOD the file(s) on the external server to 0777, then they can be changed externally:

```
<?php
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0777);
?>
```

Then use for editing:

```
<?php
$file = fopen ("ftp://login:password@server", "w");

if (!$file) {
  echo "<p>Unable to open remote file for writing.\n";
  exit;
}

/* Write the data here. */
fwrite ($file, "blablabla");
fclose ($file);
?>
```

Be aware that this can create a major security risk.

Comment: i have problem with opening - dont know how to open file - "ftp://loginpassword@server" - it does not look properly and "ftp://loginpassword@server/file.txt" too.

Answer (score 1):

Check the 'Notes' section of http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php for some clues on writing files with a URL filespec.  tl;dr: Not as easy as reading remote files via file_get_contents() might make you believe.

This is a BAD idea, though, from a security standpoint.  A couple slightly better ideas:

1. Check out ssh2_scp_send and scp the locally-changed copy of the file to the remote server. This may involve installing the SSH2 PECL extension either through your OS vendor (e.g. installing them in 'apt' for Debian-type Linux machines, 'yum' for Red Hat et al, or similar) or from PECL.
2. POST to a script on the remote server and have it update the file for you.

Comment: i am gonna use your 2. suggestion -  create a local script with post and it gonna copy files from administration server to local one

Comment: Great! I'd appreciate the upvote or whatever it is that accepts my answer -- it's my first answer on StackOverflow, I'm trying to build rep :)